# What is the best zmq socket type for distributing messages to long running worker apps?

Tags: messaging, zeromq, distributed-computing

I am working to put a distributed computing framework in place, and am investigating using 0mq as the underpinning communication layer.  Jobs, which can take up to two hours to run, can be started on any worker in a cluster (assumption that all workers in a cluster have access to the same resources and are capable of running the same jobs). The manager is responsible for monitoring the system state and triggering the jobs. The worker machines are also multi-core, but I am ignoring this portion for now.

The problem I am trying to solve is distributing jobs messages to workers, with:

- messages sit in queue until delivered
- only one worker receives a message
- a worker only receives a message IF it is capable of performing work (for example there isn't a job in process).

Ignoring the multi core, and assuming a cluster of 5 workers.  If the manager puts 7 jobs into the queue, we should have five of them should be running, one on each worker, with two remaining in queue.  When one job ends the worker should receive the next job in the queue.

I have run experiments and researched:

- PUB/SUB: the first problem is that the message will be received by all workers
- PUSH/PULL: well there is the first joiner problem, but more importantly - I cannot pause the queue while a job is in progress (it keeps taking messages)
- REQ/REP: This is the fall back, but it requires me to code everything up myself.

The questions are:

- Are there known guidelines for this  type of system, that I should be following?
- Is there a zmq socket type OR combination that will help me achieve my goal?  I like the DEALER concept, but it still looks to round robin messages regardless of the state of the recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to devise a flow control protocol, in addition to sending work messages to the workers.

A protocol I like has the workers sending Ready messages to the manager. The manager puts the ready workers into a list, and replies to the Ready messages one at a time until there is no more work. This is load balancing which is a commonly used pattern, and indeed there's the Load Balancing example in chapter 3 of the [zmq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all). I think ROUTER/DEALER sockets work best.

The beauty of load balancing is it's sheer simplicity. The manager just has to maintain a list of jobs, another list of ready workers, and reply to their Ready messages with the work. It doesn't even matter what kind of list it is, FIFO, LIFO, random.

The fact that the workers are running on multicore systems shouldn't be special. It's simply the case that workers should try to avoid starving each other of any resources, whether that's disk, memory, or CPU. Of course, that's another layer independent of the load balancing pattern.

Comment: The example I am looking at now for load balancer has a req -> router/router <- req structure.  Do you have thoughts on this? It seems to work.

Comment: Wait, a (client)req->router<->router<-req(worker) will block at the client level... Thats not what I want.

Comment: All the advice is to use ROUTER/DEALER in preference to REQ/REP because the former allows fully asynchronous messaging without blocking. The ROUTER/REP example needs to be adapted a little to convert it to ROUTER/DEALER, and with a few hours working through the examples in chapter 3 you'll get it in the end. But if you're not ready for that, you could just scroll down a couple of pages in the guide to the "ROUTER Broker and DEALER Workers" example :-) But before you commit to production, please read the whole guide several times, it's simply the best.

Comment: I have been eating the guide all week,, nothing like getting your fingernails dirty to truly understand.  I am only working on a proof of concept, so nothing is running into production.  I need the workers to only handle one request at a time, so I think a REP is the right choice on that side.  I changed the frontend to dealer - so now I am supporting DEALER->ROUTER<->ROUTER<-REQ and the previous model REQ->ROUTER<->ROUTER<-REQ  I do have some concern on coding out the DEALER and making sure it is pairing responses correctly... And timeout issues - the reply may take hours...